# namespace renaming

Tags: ros, namespace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the turtlesim node running at /ajsim/turtle1
It is subscribing to the topic /ajsim/turtle1/command_velocity

I started another node called turtle_teleop_key which publishes the topic /turtle1/command_velocity

The problem is that the node in /ajsim/turtle1 cannot subscribe to the topic at /turtle1/command_velocity

I tried the command,
[code]
rosrun turtlesim turtle_teleop_key command_velocity:=ajsim/turtle1/command_velocity
[/code]

but it doesn't work and the wiki is a little unclear about how the change the namespace. Could someone please tell me how I can make sure they are in the same namespace?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28090/namespace-renaming/) by [cassander](https://answers.ros.org/users/1815/cassander/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2012-02-21

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Remapping%20Arguments) tutorial.

You could also use:

```
export ROS_NAMESPACE=/ajsim
rosrun turtlesim turtle_teleop_key
```

This would run the teleop node under the `ajsim` namespace, and would allow you to subscribe to the topic.

**EDIT**:

I do not know of a way to change a node's namespace while it's running. If you don't want to use the ROS_NAMESPACE variable, then you would want to use [roslaunch](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML).

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cassander](https://answers.ros.org/users/1815/cassander/) on 2012-02-21**:
thank you. That worked. I was wondering if there is a way to change the namespace of a node while it is executing... so that it can continue publishing the messages in the new namespace?

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-02-22**:
To change the namespace while a node is running?

**Comment by [cassander](https://answers.ros.org/users/1815/cassander/) on 2012-02-22**:
Yes.. is it possible to change the namespace of a node while it is running? If that is not possible, then is it possible to change the namespace of a node while it is being launched on the command line using rosrun without having the export the ROS_NAMESPACE variable?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can use the following:
**rosrun turtlesim turtle_teleop_key __ns:=ajsim**
to start the teleop node using the namespace **ajsim**

---

Originally posted by [AA A](https://answers.ros.org/users/54264/aa-a/) with karma: 23 on 2020-05-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2